# How to find and replace a string in multiple files in unix?

Tags: perl, unix

I can do the find and replace a string in multiple files with the below command.

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs sed -i  's/foo/faa/g'
```

Can we do the same by using `Perl`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this command...:

```
find . -name '*.py' | xargs perl -p -i -e 's/foo/faa/g'
```

N.B.: If you want to make a backup copy of your files before changing them, provide `-i` flag with an extension... I.E.: `-i.bak`...